# Python clear list clearing wrong list?

Tags: python, list

So I have a very rudimentary understanding of python (10-week summer course split up between python and Matlab). I am trying to create a 2d list like so:

```python
data.append (samples)
data.append (matches)
data_list.append (data)
data.clear()
```

This is running in a for loop and writing each time it iterates. However, when I run it and I `print(data_list)` I get an empty list.

I have successfully ran it like so:

```python
data.append (samples)
data.append (matches)
data_list.append (data)
data = []
```

But I do not understand the difference between my two methods and why only the second one works...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an object reference in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488769/what-is-an-object-reference-in-python)

Comment: What is `samples` and `matches`?

Comment: `data_list.append(data.copy())` will solve your issue. The problem is you're putting a reference to `data` inside `data_list`, not the stuff inside `data`. So when you clear `data`, the reference inside `data_list` is now pointing to an empty list.

Comment: `samples` and `matches` are integer values. Its a program that compares your birthday to a random sample group. So I understand how the `data_list.append(data.copy())` solves this issue. It is strange that python handles that differently, because by clearing data by `data=()` is preserves the values in data_list however clearing by `.clear` it doesn't preserve the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, it is critical to understand that **everything is an object**. Of these, you have two types:

- immutable (int, float, char, str, tuple)
- mutable (list, dict, other objects, ...)

**Immutable** objects *cannot be changed*. That is, you cannot redefine a immutable:

```
1 = 0
```

That is ridiculous! You may, however, *bind* immutables to names. We call such names "variables".

```
x = 1
y = x
x = 0

# x = 0
# y = 1
```

**Mutable** objects, however, may change their internal contents:

```
x = [0, 2]
y = x
x[0] = 1

# x = [1, 2]
# y = [1, 2]
```

Notice that `y` is merely a name to the list. When you mutate the list `x` with `x[0] = 1`, you are mutating the same list that `y` is bound to.

---

Why am I telling you all this? Because:

```
data.clear()
```

**mutates** the original list that `data` is bound to.

In contrast,

```
data = ()
```

simply **rebinds** `data` to some other object.