# Updating weights manually in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

```
import torch
import math


# Create Tensors to hold input and outputs.
x = torch.linspace(-math.pi, math.pi, 2000)
y = torch.sin(x)

# For this example, the output y is a linear function of (x, x^2, x^3), so
# we can consider it as a linear layer neural network. Let's prepare the
# tensor (x, x^2, x^3).
p = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
xx = x.unsqueeze(-1).pow(p)

model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(3, 1),
    torch.nn.Flatten(0, 1)
)

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')

learning_rate = 1e-6
```

Then I print the weights

```
parameters = list(model.parameters())
print(parameters)
```

Results:

```
[Parameter containing:
tensor([[ 0.0407,  0.2680, -0.1148]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.0132], requires_grad=True)]
```

```
y_pred = model(xx)
loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
model.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
```

Updating the weights:

```
with torch.no_grad():  
    for param in model.parameters():
        param -= 1e-6 * param.grad
```

and then

```
list(model.parameters())
[Parameter containing:
 tensor([[ 0.0532,  0.2472, -0.0393]], requires_grad=True),
 Parameter containing:
 tensor([-0.0167], requires_grad=True)]
```

The weights were updated. I got confused. How is that possible? I thought just **param** variable in the for loop changed, not model.parameters().

But when change the code a bit

```
with torch.no_grad():  
    for param in model.parameters():
        param -= 1e-6
```

The weights didn't change. So I guess it related to **param.grad**. Can you guys explain to me about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`param` variable inside the loop [*references*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35488769/1714410) each element of `model.parameters()`.  Thus, updating `param` is the same as updating the elements of `model.parameters()`.

As for your second example, I think decrementing by `1e-6` is just not enough for you to see the effect. Try `param -= 1.` and see if this has any effect on `model.parameters()`.